# Hexo - how can you set page path?

Tags: hexo

I see `hexo` builds paths by convention of the file layout. Though I wish to organize files differently. Is there a way to set paths manually in page files?

E.g.
`source/abt.md`:

```
title: About me
path: '/about/me/'
```

Comment: I think you should move `abt.md` to `abt/index.md`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @piecioshka but that wasn't quite the point. It was to have an URL that is unrelated to the file path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's possible using the `--path` option:

```sh
hexo new page --path about/me/index "About me"
```

this will create `source/about/me/index.md` file with the following front matter:

```
---
title: About me
date: 2019-04-04 23:51:44
---
```

The `--path` option is not documented, but it is listed when using `hexo help new`.

By the way, the help for `hexo new` command states:

```
Usage: hexo new [layout] <title>
```

This means that the path is automatically defined from the title. Using `--path` option simply allows to specify it manually.

Note that not giving a title on the command line creates a post. For instance:

```
hexo new page --path foo/bar
```

will create `_posts/foo/bar.md` with front matter `title` set to `page`. It's not a bug: the layout is optional, while the title is not.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's not a way to organize your files differently than the default way.

Here is all the configuration you can make at the top of the file.
https://hexo.io/docs/front-matter.html